# Can't see the dock bar when starting desktop environment with startx

Tags: xorg, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, xinit

I'm using Ubuntu version 19.04. I would like to log into gnome desktop environment from TTY terminal. I used `startx` to initialize the desktop environment. I can see the top bar and run gui applications. But there's no dock bar, unless I press the Activities button. How do I make the dock bar show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `startx` its configurations are different from normal login.

you need to enable the extension `ubuntu-dock`

one of the way is to run `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` and enable the extension.

[image]

Other way is to use the below command. If you have more extensions.. you can add them too

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com']"
```

Example:

```
pratap@PRATAP:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com']"
pratap@PRATAP:~$
```

[image]

---

For a Qucik migration of some settings from normal login to `startx`

First get the `gsettings` values for the below keys when you are on normal login.

Example:

```
pratap@PRATAP:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme
'DMZ-White'
pratap@PRATAP:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
'ubuntu-mono-dark'
pratap@PRATAP:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
'Ambiance'
pratap@PRATAP:~$ gsettings list-recursively | grep enabled-extensions
org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions ['ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com', 'user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com']
pratap@PRATAP:~$ gsettings list-recursively | grep favorite-apps
org.gnome.shell favorite-apps ['ubiquity.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'org.gnome.Software.desktop', 'yelp.desktop', 'ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop']
pratap@PRATAP:~$
```

Then Create a script with below content

```
#!/bin/bash

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'DMZ-White'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'ubuntu-mono-dark'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Ambiance'
gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "['ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com', 'user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com']"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['ubiquity.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'org.gnome.Software.desktop', 'yelp.desktop', 'ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

Once you entered `startx` run the script.

For example if you have saved the script named `startx` in `/home/<user>/` then run the command `/bin/bash /home/<user>/startx`

with more workouts you can make changes to your script for your exact requirement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I've made some changes in the default settings application that comes with Ubuntu 19.04, when I've been logging in to user via the login menu. This changes don't seem to have been transfered. For example stuff the mouse and touchpad settings. Furthermore the Dock settings is missing completely from the settings menu when logging in via TTY. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Understood. Could you add to the answer the script I can use to do this (aka copy the configuration from the normal login)? Would much appreciate it!